# Problem compiling cycles with cmake: Could NOT find OpenImageIO (missing: OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY OPENIMAGEIO_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I would like to build and run the Cycles Render Engine on my Ubuntu 18.04. I made sure that all  the crucial dependencies mentioned on the Cycles repository page (https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/C/) are installed.

The problem is that when I run cmake, I get the following output:

```
sebastian@sebastian-N551JX:~$ cd Program\ Files/cycles/
sebastian@sebastian-N551JX:~/Program Files/cycles$ cd build
sebastian@sebastian-N551JX:~/Program Files/cycles/build$ cmake ..
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:36 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0043 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found GLUT: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so  
-- GLUT_FOUND=TRUE
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:275 (message):
  Policy CMP0072 is not set: FindOpenGL prefers GLVND by default when
  available.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0072" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  FindOpenGL found both a legacy GL library:

    OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

  and GLVND libraries for OpenGL and GLX:

    OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so

  OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE has not been set to "GLVND" or "LEGACY", so for
  compatibility with CMake 3.10 and below the legacy GL library will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/cmake/external_libs.cmake:71 (find_package)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so   
-- Found Glew: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so  
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenImageIO (missing: OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY
  OPENIMAGEIO_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  src/cmake/Modules/FindOpenImageIO.cmake:61 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/cmake/external_libs.cmake:81 (find_package)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/sebastian/Program Files/cycles/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/sebastian/Program Files/cycles/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

cmake is telling me that it couldn't find OpenImageIO (missing: OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY OPENIMAGEIO_INCLUDE_DIR)

I probably should say that I just recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu and I am still quite unfamiliar with cmake and make and honestly, I don't know what's going on in this particular case... I browsed the internet and StackOverflow but the solutions proposed there didn't work for me.
I guess I somehow need to tell cmake where to find the missing folders (I know they are installed) but I haven't got any idea how to do so.

If you know the issue, can you point me in the right direction. I would be more than grateful for any piece of advice I can get from you.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:
What I did so far was installing OpenImageIO via the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install openimageio-tools
```

This didn't seem to work since cmake still couldn't find the folders. 
After this, I cloned the files from the OpenImageIO repository (https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio) to

```
sebastian@sebastian-N551JX:~/Program Files/oiio$
```

Then, according to the installation guide (https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio/blob/master/INSTALL.md) I did the following commands

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

While I was doing this, some new problems arose. Here's a snipped:

```
Field3D library not found 
--     Try setting Field3D_ROOT ? 
-- GIF library not found 
--     Try setting GIF_ROOT ? 
-- Libheif library not found 
--     Try setting Libheif_ROOT ?
```

And when I tried to "make" I got the following error:

```
[ 75%] Linking CXX shared library libOpenImageIO.so
c++: error: Files/oiio/src/build-scripts/hidesymbols.map: No such file or directory
```

I will try to overcome these issues now, if somebody has an idea, please feel free to let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error messages in the **question post** as **text**, not *linked* as *image*. Please, [edit] you post and paste the error message into it. You may format the pasted error message as a *code*, with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for the friendly reminder and sorry for the unconvenience. I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: The message "Could NOT find OpenImageIO" means that CMake couldn't find the library OpenImageIO. Do you have this library **installed** on your machine? If yes, where (under which directory) it is installed?

Comment: BTW, the project's [README](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/C/) clearly notes OpenImageIO library as one of requirements.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your answer. I added an "Edit" section to my post, describing what I did. If what I wrote is not clear, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Usually for **compile** a project which uses some **library**, you need `-dev` package for that library. In your case you need to install [openimageio-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libopenimageio-dev).

Comment: @Tsyvarev that did the trick! Everything's working now like a charm. I guess that I'll need some time to get comfortable with Ubuntu. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo apt install libopenimageio-dev`
(on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)